# SendGrid - How to hide the "View Opt Out Preferences" button from Opt-Out Preferences page

Tags: sendgrid

We only enable unsubscribe links for all the marketing emails.(we have unsubscribe groups for that) So we don't provide unsubscribe links for other types of email, for example, a payment request email.

However, we discovered that on the Preferences page, users can still choose to Opt-Out of all Emails (global unsubscribe) thus they will no longer receive any email from us including the payment request. So wondering how could I disable this "View Opt Out Preferences" button so that users can only Opt-out one single group?

[image]
[image]

**Edit Sep 20:**
there is no such setting for custom unsubscribe link. Offical docu is out of date.
https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/create-and-manage-unsubscribe-groups#using-a-custom-unsubscribe-link

[image]
[image]

Comment: I can't turn on "Subscription Tracking" as I don't want a unsubscribe link in some important email

Comment: btw, I'm use code editor

Comment: This opt out is for emails sent by lists. If you are sending payment requests, that should not be delivered to the list, but directly as a transactional email.

Comment: @philnash Hi Philnash, I'm using sendgrid npm client to send email out. How can I tell SendGrid this is a transactional email? The problem I have is users can manually do global unsubscribe from marketing email. Then they won't receive any email from my sendGrid account. That's why I need to hide that "Opt out of all emails" button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

Sorry it's taken me a while to get to this. I've been chasing down what can be done here. There are a few options:

### Subusers

If you are on a Pro account or higher, you can set up subusers within your account. The recommendation is to set up a subuser for your marketing emails and a different subuser for your transactional emails. That way unsubscribes from the marketing list won't affect the transactional email side of things. You can read about [setting up subuser accounts here](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/subusers).

### Create your own unsubscribe page

Rather than using the SendGrid provided unsubscribe page, that allows users to get to the "Opt out of all emails" button, you can create your own unsubscribe page. You can [add a custom unsubscribe link to your emails](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/create-and-manage-unsubscribe-groups#using-a-custom-unsubscribe-link). You can then [use the API to add the email address to one of your unsubscribe groups](https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/suppressions-suppressions/add-suppressions-to-a-suppression-group).

### Bypass suppressions

You can set the `bypass_list_management` filter to true when sending your mail to ignore all unsubscribe groups/suppressions. This seems like a last resort sort of fix, rather than something you should use for all transactional emails. The docs are fairly strongly worded on this:

> It is important to respect unsubscribes, and these filters should be used only when it is absolutely necessary to deliver a message to recipients who have unsubscribed from your emails. For example, you may use these filters to deliver messages that you are legally required to send to all recipients or important security messages like a password reset.

Check out more on [bypass list management](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/index-suppressions#bypass-list-management).

Comment: Thanks philnash, for "Create your own unsubscribe page”, I think the docu is out of date. I'm using code editor for the template and don't see any option there to custom unsubscribe link?

Comment: I edited the original post to include screen shot for out of date documentation

Comment: That's not out of date, but it does refer to email designs created as part of a marketing campaign, either a single send or an automation. It doesn't apply to regular templates that aren't part of a marketing campaign. In the code editor, can you just include your own custom link rather than it filling in with the default unsubscribe link?

Comment: Hi Philnash, sorry I'm not sure whether I got what you suggested. currently, I'm adding "{{{unsubscribe}}}" tag in the code to show the link for it to work with my unsubscribe group. Seems like no way that I can just change the page link for it.  I still want SendGrid unsubscribe group to handle all the unsubscription but just need a differnt HTML page.

Comment: <a href="{{{unsubscribe}}}">Click here to unsubscribe.</a>  this is the code that I added into my template. How can you change the page link while still let sendgrid to manage the unsubscribe group?

Comment: When I said you could build your own page, you still have to build the page, create your own form to handle user input and then use the API to unsubscribe the user from the subscription group. You can add a custom link for that when your template is a single send or automation within marketing campaigns.

Comment: Thanks philnash, that makes sense.

Comment: @philnash Now in tracking settings there is "SendGrid Landing Page HTML" option. It says SendGrid will host the landing page for you and you can customize the HTML of that page here. But it looks like online ms word editor. It looks like you can add text and pictures etc. but what I want to know is do I need to put a full html page structure or does I just need to put my text there and sendgrid does the rest?(Although I would ask how does it know where to put the text) I tried both options but I could never see a different page then custom sendgrid page

Comment: Hi @DenizKaradağ, this seems like a different question that would be better with more context, explanations and maybe even screenshots. Can you ask a new question and I'll see if I can help.