# SendGrid - change unsubscribe page without turn on " Subscription Tracking"?

Tags: sendgrid

Currently, I'm using unsubscribe group and {{{unsubscribe}}} tag to manage unsubscription. I don't want to turn on "subscription Tracking" as I don't want to provide unsubscribe link in some emails.

when user click the link, they is being redirected to this page, wondering how could I modify this page? like change language to French, delete "View Opt Out Preferences" button?

[image]

Comment: btw, i'm using code editor

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SendGrid - How to hide the "View Opt Out Preferences" button from Opt-Out Preferences page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69214151/sendgrid-how-to-hide-the-view-opt-out-preferences-button-from-opt-out-prefer)

Comment: You already asked [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69214151/sendgrid-how-to-hide-the-view-opt-out-preferences-button-from-opt-out-prefer).